# SymPy outputs a numerical result when a symbolic expression is expected

Tags: python, sympy

I'ld like my SymPy results to be displayed as precise results and not as decimal results. I looked through the SymPy documentation, but couldn't find anything helpful.

To illustrate the problem, here is some example code:

```
from sympy import *
u = symbols("u")
integrate((1+u)**(1/2), (u, 0, 1))
```

Output:

```
1.21895141649746
```

Expected result:

```
(4/3)*sqrt(2)-(2/3)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that SymPy will simplify expressions containing floats and so removes those symbolic expressions. Although the expression doesn't look like a float, the division `1/2` is done with standard Python, internally represented as `0.5`.

The solution is to first convert one of the parts of the fraction to a SymPy object. The easiest way is with the function `S`, as in:

```py
from sympy import *
u = symbols("u")
print(integrate((1+u)**(S(1)/2), (u, 0, 1)))
```

which outputs the desired `-2/3 + 4*sqrt(2)/3`.

The [gotcha section](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#symbolic-expressions) of the documentation tries to explain this behavior.